# Kohana ORM JOIN with OR statement

Tags: orm, kohana

I need create query like this

```
JOIN users
        ON dialogs.`user_id` <> '.$this->user->id.'
        AND dialogs.user_id=users.id
        OR dialogs.`to` <> '.$this->user->id.'
        AND dialogs.`to`=users.id
```

But every time when I use on() method ORM adds "AND" statement. Is is possible adding OR instead of AND?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `user_id <> '.$this->user->id.'` and `dialogs.to <> '.$this->user->id.'` must in the `where` clausel. There you can use [or_where](http://kohanaframework.org/3.0/guide/api/Database_Query_Builder_Update#or_where).